# Convert double to string (C#)

Tags: c#, string, double, converters

Convert a double from `12.45` to a string like `00001245` (length of the string = 8).

How could I do that?

Comment: Please provide more info about requirements and limitations. It will be always 8 character string? What with numbers which have more than 8 digits?

Comment: Will it always have precisely 2 dp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:D8}", (int)(12.45 * 100));
```

Comment: I get an exception on this: _"Format specifier was invalid."_

Comment: A cast to `int` is missing. `D` is for integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

- Multiply it with 100, to get rid of the `.`
- Cast it to an `int`, to get rid of leftover decimals.
- Convert it to a `string` with `ToString()`
- And pad it on the left with a totalsize of 8 with `'0'`

---

```
double d = 12.45;
string value = ((int)(d * 100)).ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your double always has 2 digits after comma, looks like you need to multiply with `100` and use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) method until you get 8 length of string.

```
double d = 12.45;
Console.WriteLine((d * 100).ToString().PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

Output will be;

```
00001245
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/HVGG1W)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done:

```
String.Format("{0:00000000}", 12.45 * 100)
```

Comment: You can update your currently answer instead of adding another one. This would be better in my opinion `;)`

Comment: I posted it as another answer because it uses another method. I don't want to mix good/bad solutions :)